# Redirect siege output into file

Tags: bash, siege

I´m trying to redirect `siege` statistics into a log file for a further analysis, but I´m not able to do it. I´ve tried it by using `>>` to redirect the output, but there is not possible to redirect the final statistics.

Another option is to use the log file in `/var/siege/log` but I just need the statistics of the last test, the ones which appear at the end of the test

Any ideas?

Comment: does adding a `2>&1` to the end of your cmd (after `>>/../output`) help?

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. I had no idea it could be related with the error output.